# Deploy my laravel project to shared hosting with github actions

Tags: laravel, yaml, cpanel, github-actions

I added GitHub action `main.yml` to my Laravel project to the shared hosting for automated deployment.

The deployment is working well, but the project was placed outside `public_html` because of the path I specified

```
- server_dir: /home5/app/public_html/
```

I want the project files to be in the `public_html` folder. The following code is the yaml configuration:

```
name: Glory Deploy Production
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: Deploying...
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.username}}
        password: ${{ secrets.password}}
        server_dir: /home5/app/public_html/
```

How can I change the path to the `public_html` directory?

Comment: Thanks for your excellent question post, It is worth over a thousand answers. It saved my hours. I found your mistake and I'll post an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering your ftp user is a default user that has root path

```
server_dir: "public_html/"
```

If your user not has the root path you must consider its path until  `public_html`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your mistake is `server_dir`. It should be `server-dir`. In my case, I needed to upload codes into a sub-folder so I wrote like the following:

```
server-dir: ./sub-folder/
```

**HINT**: The trailing `/` at the end is mandatory and the default of `server-dir` is `./`.